# Run installation command in an already existing docker image (not container)?

Tags: python, docker

I have built an image with my docker container found in:

https://github.com/brando90/hbf_tensorflow_code/blob/master/docker_files/tf_cpu_py3.4/Dockerfile

and eventually the system decided to have one of the python modules disappear for some strange reason (completely inexplicable to me). It gave an error and I ran a container with bash and installed the missing python library. I ran:

```
apt-get install python3-tk
```

and it installed the missing library (that got uninstalled magically) in the running container and its all good. Now things seem to work. Though, is there no way run this installation command in the already existing docker image without removing it or without making a new docker file with that command add somewhere?

Also does anyone have any guesses on what could have happened or even track what could have happened? I did try just re making the docker image again from scratch but it kept having the error. Does it mean I need to add that command (which seems a bit random) in my Dockerfile?

Comment: It seems like you are asking several questions here. Can you narrows it down to one so that it isn't so broad?

Comment: @AndyShinn sure, my question from the title is I have a docker image that randomly decided to uninstall stuff, can I run an installation script without removing the image itself? Sort if like `docker run_cmd <my_img> re_install_python_stuff`.

Comment: I understand. I'll try to answer the Docker way of how you typically handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking in Docker terms, there are two ways to handle this.

The first is to just add the missing package to the `Dockerfile` and rebuild the image. I would just append the `python3-tk` to your other `apt-get install` commands and rebuild it.

The second option is to save a new image based off of an existing container. You would use the `docker commit` command if you already have a container running based on the original image and you have fixed the issue. Just run `docker commit <container_id> <new_image_name>`.

Remember, containers are running an overlay filesystem on top of your base image. They are not writing directly to the images. Thus, if you are adding packages to a container, those changes are not immediately reflected in the base image.